# ¿Por qué no me salen todos los valores en los procedimientos en Programación BBDD?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-procedimiento, mysqlprocedure

Crea un procedimiento que reciba como parámetro de entrada una forma de pago y devuelva como salida los valores de la siguiente lista para esa forma de pago:

- el pago de máximo valor
- El pago de mínimo valor
- El valor medio de los pagos realizados
- La suma de todos los pagos
- El número total de pagos

```
delimiter //
    drop procedure if exists ejer3;//
    create procedure ejer3(in vforma_pago varchar(40), out maxPago float(14,2),
    out minPago float(14,2), medioPago float(14,2), sumPago float(14,2),
    totalPago float(14,2))
    
    begin
    
        select max(total), min(total), avg(total), sum(total), count(total)
        into maxPago, minPago, medioPago, sumPago, totalPago
        from pago
        where forma_pago=vforma_Pago;
    end;
    
    //
    
    call ejer3('PayPal', @maxPago, @minPago, @medioPago, @sumPago, @totalPago);
    select  @maxPago, @minPago, @medioPago, @sumPago, @totalPago;
```

Me deberían dar estos valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al ejecutarlo me da esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

el error está en la declaración de tu stored procedure, no estás colocando el tipo "OUT" en tus parámetros de salida, por eso está devolviendo NULL:

```
medioPago float(14,2), 
sumPago float(14,2), 
totalPago float(14,2)
```

Debería estar así:

```
out medioPago float(14,2), 
out sumPago float(14,2), 
out totalPago float(14,2)
```

Comment: Muy buena solución y @Rosa si la solución te funciona no te olvides de darle el voto positivo y de marcar el ✅  para que se resuelva